# Setup Ubuntu on a new drive - help needed

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I have an old laptop which had an HDD failure.
So I'm trying to fix it... got a new 128gb Solid state HDD.
However, the windows(visa) sticker with the product code has over time lost some of the letters. I found ubuntu as a free OS alternative.
I have formatted the new HDD using an external SATA caddy and can view it using my netbook (no cd drive or usb stick).

How can i setup a bootable ubuntu install on the new external SSD so when i plug it into the laptop i am attempting to fix, it all boots up correctly?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether your old laptop will boot from an external hdd.

If it does, then:

**To install Ubuntu to your external SSD drive, with no usb or dvd:**

1. On your netbook with no usb and cd-drive: download the *.iso file of your desired Ubuntu flavour.
2. Install [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).
3. Run Unetbootin, select the downloaded *.iso, and make sure you install it to the Hard Drive. (the preserved space you can leave at 0 MB).
4. When this is successful, reboot, and select Unetbooting from the menu. This should start the LiveCD version of Ubuntu, and you should now be able to install Ubuntu to the external SSD drive. Install the bootloader to the SSD drive.

**To run the new Ubuntu:**

Set the BIOS to boot from the SSD drive.